# Load Testing for Amazon server EC2 with httperf

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-testing, httperf

I am using Amazon EC2 services for my web services. I would like to know the maximum number of users that can simultaneously use my web services.

For this, I performed load testing using httperf from the client system.

When the Reply Rate is nearly equal to Request Rate then we can tell that the server is doing well. But for request rate 5 I was getting the reply rate as 1 when testing was done for 20 samples. The value of time-out was 5. Also, many requests were timed out; 300 out of 500 were timed out.

1. Is this because I am conducting the test on the client? How do I install httperf on the server?
2. Am I doing something wrong? The following is the command that I used on the load testing tool with httperf: `httperf --server=web-service-url --rate=5 --num-conns=500 --timeout=5`
3. Is httperf a good tool for load testing?
4. Does Amazon provide any other mechanisms for load testing?
5. The above load testing was done for a web service of type GET. Do we need to conduct separate load testing for POST request and if so, how do we do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo apt-get install httperf`. Also, you can build from [source](http://code.google.com/p/httperf/).
2. It actually depends on what youre trying to test. Use more options, `--uri`, `--retry-on-failure` etc. A full list of options [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/httperf).
3. Yes, it is. You can even replay from log files.
4. No.
5. use `--method=POST` ( use `method` arg with *GET* / *POST* / *PUT*)